# Can address of anonymous derived class be assigned to base class pointer C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that in C++ you can assign derived classes to pointers of base classes. This requires a `new` operator. I though maybe I could do something similar with anonymous class instantiation (unsure of exact terminology). Here is an example of what I tried to do. This compiles fine, but gives a runtime error. Could someone please explain the reasoning of the runtime error and also if what I am trying to do is possible?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int num;
    Derived() : num(0) {}
    Derived(int num) : num(num) {}
    virtual void show() { cout << num << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Base* ptr;
    /* 
     * I understand that I could do 
     * ptr = new Derived();
     * but I was wondering if I could do something with anonymous classes
     * as mentioned the following line compiles, but gives runtime error
     */
    ptr = &Derived();
    ptr->show();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Here `ptr = &Derived();` the `Derived` instance will cease to exist immediately after the statement.

Comment: "&Derived()" is meaningless gobbledygook. Whatever this is supposed to achieve, it's the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Aside: you forgot to make the destructor virtual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually it wouldn't even compile because `&` cannot be applied to an rvalue.  (Unless that is a class rvalue that overloads `operator&`, which isn't the case here)

Comment: @Hurkyl Technically not necessary since no Derived is deleted through a base class pointer (but a good idea anyway)

Comment: @M.M Yup, the 1st version of my comment used _would_ actually, because I suspected so :-) ...

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I didn't know `&Derived()` would create a temporary object. I do now. Again thank you all for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary objects are temporary. They are destroyed at the end of the statement that spawned them. Since you need an object that persists for a while, you have to do something different.

(an exception is if you bind a temporary to a const reference; then the object will last until the end of the reference's scope)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ptr = &Derived();
```

You are creating a temporary `Derived` and storing the pointer to the temporary object in ptr. Because it's temporary, it is destroyed immediately following this line and ptr is referencing an invalid object. Just make sure that the lifetime of your object survives all references to it:

```
Derived d;
ptr = &d;
```

Comment: Your final suggestion is good, but the first line fails to compile, so your commentary doesn't really apply

Comment: @M.M He's probably using an older version of MSVC which used to accept it.